# How to get the sheet name from a cell when using a function such as SUM or ArrayFormula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(Morten!$M4:$M400))
```

How can I replace `Morten` with the contents of a cell, ie cell `C13`, so that `ArrayFormula` will still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `Indirect` function?

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(Indirect(C13&"!M4:M400")))
```

But why wrap the `Sum` with an `ArrayFormula`? `Sum` already works with a range like that.
Well, I'll guess you probably simplified the formula to post, removing the part that made `ArrayFormula` necessary.

Comment: Thanks, this works ! I wasnt aware that Sum supported different sheets, i thought you could only do it through ArrayFormula.